# Python exception type object inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, exception

I need to retrieve the name of the object in which an error has occured. The error is catched in a try exception statement. The error type as returned by `err_type, value, traceback = sys.exc_info()` looks like this:

```
In [1]: err_type
Out[2]: mainsite.models.PurchaseOrder.DoesNotExist
```

I need to retrieve 'PurchaseOrder' as a string. The idea is to get the parent object and then use `parent.__name__`.However if I write `err_type.__bases__` the result is:

```
In [3]: err_type.__bases__
Out[4]: (django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist,)
```

I don't know what is happening here, the Exception type is not a child of PurchaseOrder, but somehow it knows that the problem was in that object. How can I retrive "PurchaseOrder" from the Exception?

I am doing this in Django, but it seems to be a general python topic.

Comment: Is the module containing your `PurchaseOrder` class also called `PurchaseOrder.py`? In `mainsite.models.PurchaseOrder.DoesNotExist` it looks more like it's fully qualifying the module that `DoesNotExist` is from and *not* the object that threw the error.

Comment: It looks more like `DoesNotExist` is a nested class inside `PurchaseOrder`, but I agree that this output definitely **does not** say anything about what object was responsible for the error.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica oooo that is a very good point. I hadn't considered that, but I think you're right about it being a nested class.

Comment: @xgord no, PurchaseOrder is in models module. It is a class itself, not a module, but inherits from Django models.Model. It has the Excetion through its parent class I guess.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica in case is a nested class, how can I retrieve `PurchaseOrder` from the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Here's two approaches.

You can already obtain a string:

```
names = str(err_type).split('.')
```

Perhaps you'd like to pick out your favorite component.

---

Alternatively, you may find that

```
value.__mro__
```

reveals what you were looking for.
It will show all parents in a [multiple inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__) (mixin) situation.

---

It's worth point out that a single `catch Exception:`
may be a poor fit for you here.
Consider using a more fine grained approach:

```
    try:
        result = query()

    catch mainsite.models.PurchaseOrder.DoesNotExist:
        handle_missing_purchase_order()

    catch mainsite.models.Approval.DoesNotExist:
        handle_missing_approval()

    catch Exception as e:
        handle_unknown_error(e)
```